# How to lock modifiers other than Shift

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-layout, xkb

I have a custom keyboard layout which heavily uses modifiers for navigation and commands. It works great when I have both of my hands on the keyboard, but now I'm trying to configure my keypad to be a partial alternative that can be used with only one hand. The simplest way to do this would be by defining some keys to act like CapsLock does, only for other modifiers like Ctrl or Hyper, locking them until pressed again. Is there a way to do this, maybe using `xkb` or some `interception`-plugin?

Comment: Probably - but read the [spec](https://www.x.org/releases/current/doc/libX11/XKB/xkblib.html).

Answer (score 1):

A quick hack is to use `xdotool` to press the modifier key, but not release it. To test:

```
xdotool keydown shift; sleep 5; xdotool keyup shift
```

This definitely makes keys typed after the first command appear shifted for me.